# C Function returning (seemingly) random integers

Tags: c, function, double, program-entry-point

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double abs_diff(double x, double y) {
  double a = x - y;

  if ( a < 0 ) {
        a = -a;
  }

  printf ("$i", a);

  return 0;
}

int main() {
  abs_diff( 1.0, 4.0 );

  return 0;
}
```

I compile the code just fine. When I run the program, however, it returns seemingly random and different numbers. The program is supposed to print the absolute value of two numbers.

When i change the variable a into an integer, the problem disappears and prints an integer, but I need the result to be a double in case a double is entered. I think it has something to do with the return value? Have exhausted most of my options.

Thank you for any help or suggestions!

Comment: `printf ("$i", a);` mean `printf ("%i", a);`(for `int`) but true is `printf ("%lf", a);` (for `double`)

Answer (score 3):

Problem is printf formatting.

You must use %lf for double output, so:

```
printf ("%lf", a);
```

Comment: Just about to downvote it and you edited > <

Comment: But it's still not right...

Comment: It was just a typo, u can edit it, instead of downvoteing...

Comment: "You must use %lf for double output" No and in fact only `%f` is legal, since the length modifier of `l`(ell) doesn't apply to `double` (see `man 3 printf`). However most implements of libc would treat `%lf` as `%f`

Comment: @starrify: I thought so, too. But no, it's allowed (`l` has no effect on `f`). C90 left it undefined, however.

Comment: @mafso Yes that's true and I've just checked the standards again. However by "No" I meant he said the OP _must_ use `%lf`. Thank you anyway :)